# Why Can I add a String and a Int in Bash

Tags: string, bash, variables, integer

```
a="5"
b=1
c=$((a+b)
echo $c
```

c prints out 6

```
a="banana"
b=1
c=$((a+b))
echo $c
```

c prints out 1

How does bash recognize a="5" as an integer? Why does a="banana" become 0?

Comment: see this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232384/argument-string-to-integer-in-bash

Comment: `a="5"` is *exactly* the same as `a=5`.  And in each case, a is a string.

Comment: And, try `a=banana; banana=9; c=1; echo $((a + c))`

Comment: @Clicky -- `declare -p a` will show `a` in an unambiguous form that includes any information about whether it's local, global, exported, flagged as an array, etc -- so if you want to prove to yourself that `a="5"` and `a=5` are identical, perform each of them followed by `declare -p a`.

Comment: So why does banana = 0. Is a string that isn't an integer just defaulted to 0? Why is banana + 1 = 1?

Comment: @Clicky Yes, in an arithmetic context, a string is recursively expanded as a parameter until either a integer or an undefined variable is encountered. Undefined variables are treated as zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash knows nothing about integers as a true data type for variables.

Arithmetic expressions parse strings to convert them to integers internally.

You can declare a variable as an integer, like this :

```
declare -i var
```

This will not really make the variable an integer, it will still be usable as any variable.  It will, however, cause assignment attempts to be interpreted as arithmetic expressions (and uninitialized variables they contain as having value 0).

For instance :

```
a=1
b=2
declare -i var
var=a+b+3
echo $var # Prints 6
```

I cannot state this authoritatively, but I expect "integer" variables to simply be a shortcut to make any assignment behave as if it were enclosed in `$(())`.

Comment: Correct that `declare -i` is just sugar (makes code less portable, but doesn't improve performance -- so it's sugar I'd tend to suggest not using). Specifically, the flag it sets is `att_integer` -- which is almost entirely unused outside `variables.c`.

Comment: (though do look for references through the macro `integer_p`, if you're curious).